# Referenced bean 'EntityManagerFactory' not found and nullPointerException springboot mysql

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, nullpointerexception, entitymanager

Im trying to get data from a mysql database and im using an interface with the tag @repository that extends from CrudRepository but it says nullPointerException when i try to call any method like count() or findAll().

Also i have a warning saying = Referenced bean 'entityManagerFactory' not found

I have tried deleting the .m2 folder , adding the @Service tag on the class on which im calling the Repository interface.

I have already made my application.properties file and added this tags on the application class which has the main of the project= @ComponentScan, @ServletComponentScan, @SpringBootApplication

```
> Main class

@ComponentScan
@ServletComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class EngineApplication (){
```

```
> Blockquote

//Class that uses the repository interface#

@Service
public class EngineServiceBean {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceRepository serviceRepository;
```

```
> Blockquote

//Use of the repository in engineServiceBean

serviceRepository.count();
```

```
> Blockquote

//serviceRepository

@Repository
@Transactional
public interface ServiceRepository extends CrudRepository<Wsg_service, Integer>{

}
```

```
> Blockquote

//Entity

@Entity
public class Wsg_service {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
```

```
> Blockquote

//Application.properties

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=TRUE
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase
spring.datasource.username=myusername
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
```

[warning entity manager factory not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZp5J.png)

I think the problem is on the autowired tag and spring boot not finding the right component to process the actions i need , but since im using all those tags i really dont know what else to do .

Comment: You don't need `@ComponentScan` and `@ServletComponentScan`. Your image shows an Eclipse warning. Have you try to run the application?

Comment: Hello , yes but when i try to call the repository it shows an error saying NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't run the applicaiton yet try:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = test2
spring.datasource.password = test123

## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
```

if you have change to:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

As for your clases:

- Only use `@SpringBootApplication` in your main class
- no need to use `@Repository` and `@Transactional` in your repository

Try it, it should work!

Comment: Hello , thanks for your answer but i get a null pointer exception when i try to call my repository.